# Relationship between duality and absolute reality

Tags: reality, dualism

"A problem is only a problem when there's a solution. We exist in a world of duality: positive vs negative, happiness vs sorrow, light vs darkness. The contrastive relationship helps us understand the world, yet it also obscures the existence of an absolute reality. If there's no solution to a probelm, then it's not a probelm anymore. It's a fact that we just have to accept."

I came across this quote on the internet. It makes me wonder that is duality required to support the existence of an absolute reality? We only know something is absolute when there's something that's a relative. But in another way if something is absolutely absolute then it's absolute. Why does it need anything to sustain it or make it perceivable?

Comment: Is there nothing absolute in A=A?  No duality there.

Comment: If A=A then A != A. One of the constructs is based another. Even the arithmetic sign 
of inequality demonstrates that. How's it not relative? @JKusin

Comment: You asked for duality-free, absolute existence. A=A has no duality and is absolute and exists without any further knowing. A can be anything and the form holds. That is absolute formal knowledge. I’m not sure what A = !A means, maybe you mean !A = !A?

Comment: A != A means A doesn't equal to A. LaTex doesn't work in the comment so I use the notation use in programming. When I was studying Principa Mathematica, the professor said that all the axioms are assumed to be true. But doesn't that mean axioms are absolutely true because we assumed so? If we don't then it's not true anymore.

Comment: I dug myself a hole using formal knowledge. It's not a good way to answer your question imo. I hope you get an answer, but semantics, which I think is required, is a huge arena.

Comment: @Aviv Lo Could you please define how you use 'absolute' and then name an object or a property which is absolute in your sense? What does mean 'absolutely absolute' and what is 'absolute reality'. Possibly the problem becomes easier when focusing first on a simple concrete situation und using simple terms.

Comment: @JoWehler "Ultimate reality, as is unaffected by the beliefs or limitations of any finite being" This is the dictionary definition, which I think could be use in this context.

Comment: @Aviv Lo I am sceptical that you found the correct definition, cf. e.g. Merriam-Webster: 'ultimate reality = something that is the supreme, final, and fundamental power in all reality'. - Concerning your definition: In general, reality is always unaffected by human beliefs. Otherwise our beliefs could act by magic. - What is your opinion about the other points of my question?

Comment: @JoWehler I got the definition from wiki dictionary. It seems like there are many definitions. I think we should define reality before we can continue the discussion. What I can think of now is that reality can be a physical matter such as water. It exists long before humans do. The H2O bond holds before we came up with the periodic table. So everything that can exist independent of human existence or interference can be deemed as absolute. However, I think the quote involves human contexts. Problems and solutions are fabricated concepts. A solution can't exists without a problem, vice versa.